# What is "__docformat__" used for in Python?

Tags: python, coding-style, documentation, pep

I have been coding for about a year now in Python and I have just come across some code in a [Theano tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/mlp.py) that declares a variable at the top of the file:

```
__docformat__ = 'restructedtext en'
```

Searching the internet produced [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/#choice-of-docstring-format) PEP documentation. Although it still doesn't clearly explain when / why you would want to specify this variable.

Should I be declaring it at the top of all my Python code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point of the `__docformat__` is to allow python documentation generator tools such as [epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) to know how to properly parse the module documentation (e.g. which markup language to expect).

From the [epydoc docs](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/othermarkup.html):

> To specify the markup language for a module, you should define a module-level string variable __docformat__, containing the name of the module's markup language. The name of the markup language may optionally be followed by a language code (such as en for English). Conventionally, the definition of the __docformat__ variable immediately follows the module's docstring

However, many tools such as `epydoc` also support specifying the markup language via command-line (e.g. `epydoc --docformat restructuredtext`), so there is no strict need to include the docformat. It's more just whatever the coding conventions are for your project or organization.

Comment: What does it mean if this line is in a comment rather than defining an actual string?